# Slideshow created using only HTML and CSS not working well on Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm trying to create a basic portfolio website using only HTML and CSS. To display my projects I decided to create a slideshow using anchor tags.

The slideshow works fine if it's the only thing on the page or if it is the last part of the page (i.e. there's some content like about me, hero section above it). However, if we add some content below the slideshow it doesn't work well. In such cases, I have to scroll down the page and then click the button again to be able to move to the next slide.

I'm not able to figure out what is causing this issue.

PS: The slideshow is working fine on Safari but not on Chrome.

[Here's the fiddle:](https://jsfiddle.net/_qwerty_/g976tapd/)
(The slideshow is working fine in the fiddle.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Slideshow error</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Press+Start+2P&family=Space+Grotesk:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.2.1/css/all.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <main>
            <div id="projects-display">
                <div class="sparkles">
                    <a href="#"><img src="/images/sparkles.png" alt="sparkles" class="sparkle sparkle-1L"></a>
                    <a href="#"><img src="/images/sparkles.png" alt="sparkles" class="sparkle sparkle-1R"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="projectsdisplay-content">
                    <p class="interjection">Okay, so here are the projects..</p>
                    <div class="carousel">
                        <div id="slide-1" class="slide-item">
                            <div class="slide-content">
                                <div class="slide-img">
                                    <img src="" alt="screenshot of project">
                                </div>
                                <div class="slide-text for-desktop">
                                    <div class="paras">
                                        <p class="project-num">01</p>
                                        <p class="project-name">project name</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="buttons">
                                        <div class="button slide-button">
                                            <a class="slide-button-text" href="">View code</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="button slide-button">
                                            <a class="slide-button-text" href="">Learn more</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="paras for-mobile">
                                    <p class="project-num">01</p>
                                    <p class="project-name">project name</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="buttons for-mobile">
                                    <div class="button slide-button">
                                        <a class="slide-button-text" href="">View code</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="button slide-button">
                                        <a class="slide-button-text" href="">Learn more</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="slide-nav">
                                <a href="#slide-5"><i class="fa-solid fa-angle-left slide1-arrow-left"></i></a>
                                <a href="#slide-2"><i class="fa-solid fa-angle-right slide1-arrow-right"></i></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="slide-indicator">
                                <div class="circle current-slide"></div>
                                <div class="circle"></div>
                                <div class="circle"></div>
                                <div class="circle"></div>
                                <div class="circle"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="slide-2" class="slide-item">
                          <div class="slide-content">
                            <div class="slide-img">
                                <img src="" alt="screenshot of project">
                            </div>
                            <div class="slide-text for-desktop">
                                <div class="paras">
                                    <p class="project-num">02</p>
                                    <p class="project-name">project name</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="buttons">
                                    <div class="button slide-button">
                                        <a class="slide-button-text" href="">View code</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="button slide-button">
                                        <a class="slide-button-text" href="">Learn more</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="paras for-mobile">
                                <p class="project-num">02</p>
                                <p class="project-name">project name</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="buttons for-mobile">
                                <div class="button slide-button">
                                    <a class="slide-button-text" href="">View code</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="button slide-button">
                                    <a class="slide-button-text" href="">Learn more</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="slide-nav">
                            <a href="#slide-1"><i class="fa-solid fa-angle-left slide2-arrow-left"></i></a>
                            <a href="#slide-3"><i class="fa-solid fa-angle-right slide2-arrow-right"></i></a>
                          </div>
                          <div class="slide-indicator">
                            <div class="circle"></div>
                            <div class="circle current-slide"></div>
                            <div class="circle"></div>
                            <div class="circle"></div>
                            <div class="circle"></div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="slide-3" class="slide-item">
                          <div class="slide-content">
                            <div class="slide-img">
                                <img src="" alt="screenshot of project">
                            </div>
                            <div class="slide-text for-desktop">
                                <div class="paras">
                                    <p class="project-num">03</p>
                                    <p class="project-name">project name</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="buttons">
                                    <div class="button slide-button">
                                        <a class="slide-button-text" href="">View code</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="button slide-button">
                                        <a class="slide-button-text" href="">Learn more</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="paras for-mobile">
                                <p class="project-num">03</p>
                                <p class="project-name">project name</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="buttons for-mobile">
                                <div class="button slide-button">
                                    <a class="slide-button-text" href="">View code</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="button slide-button">
                                    <a class="slide-button-text" href="">Learn more</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="slide-nav">
                            <a href="#slide-2"><i class="fa-solid fa-angle-left slide3-arrow-left"></i></a>
                            <a href="#slide-4"><i class="fa-solid fa-angle-right slide3-arrow-right"></i></a>
                          </div>
                          <div class="slide-indicator">
                            <div class="circle"></div>
                            <div class="circle"></div>
                            <div class="circle current-slide"></div>
                            <div class="circle"></div>
                            <div class="circle"></div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="slide-4" class="slide-item">
                          <div class="slide-content">
                            <div class="slide-img">
                                <img src="" alt="screenshot of project">
                            </div>
                            <div class="slide-text for-desktop">
                                <div class="paras">
                                    <p class="project-num">04</p>
                                    <p class="project-name">project name</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="buttons">
                                    <div class="button slide-button">
                                        <a class="slide-button-text" href="">View code</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="button slide-button">
                                        <a class="slide-button-text" href="">Learn more</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="paras for-mobile">
                                <p class="project-num">04</p>
                                <p class="project-name">project name</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="buttons for-mobile">
                                <div class="button slide-button">
                                    <a class="slide-button-text" href="">View code</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="button slide-button">
                                    <a class="slide-button-text" href="">Learn more</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="slide-nav">
                            <a href="#slide-3"><i class="fa-solid fa-angle-left slide4-arrow-left"></i></a>
                            <a href="#slide-5"><i class="fa-solid fa-angle-right slide4-arrow-right"></i></a>
                          </div>
                          <div class="slide-indicator">
                            <div class="circle"></div>
                            <div class="circle"></div>
                            <div class="circle"></div>
                            <div class="circle current-slide"></div>
                            <div class="circle"></div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="slide-5" class="slide-item">
                          <div class="slide-content">
                            <div class="slide-img">
                                <img src="" alt="screenshot of project">
                            </div>
                            <div class="slide-text for-desktop">
                                <div class="paras">
                                    <p class="project-num">05</p>
                                    <p class="project-name">project name</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="buttons">
                                    <div class="button slide-button">
                                        <a class="slide-button-text" href="">View code</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="button slide-button">
                                        <a class="slide-button-text" href="">Learn more</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="paras for-mobile">
                                <p class="project-num">05</p>
                                <p class="project-name">project name</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="buttons for-mobile">
                                <div class="button slide-button">
                                    <a class="slide-button-text" href="">View code</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="button slide-button">
                                    <a class="slide-button-text" href="">Learn more</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="slide-nav">
                            <a href="#slide-4"><i class="fa-solid fa-angle-left slide5-arrow-left"></i></a>
                            <a href="#slide-1"><i class="fa-solid fa-angle-right slide5-arrow-right"></i></a>
                          </div>
                          <div class="slide-indicator">
                            <div class="circle"></div>
                            <div class="circle"></div>
                            <div class="circle"></div>
                            <div class="circle"></div>
                            <div class="circle current-slide"></div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="contact-me">
                <div class="sparkles">
                    <a href="#"><img src="/images/sparkles.png" alt="sparkles" class="sparkle sparkle-2L"></a>
                    <a href="#"><img src="/images/sparkles.png" alt="sparkles" class="sparkle sparkle-2R"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="contactme-content">
                    <h2>contact me</h2>
                    <form action="" method="post">
                        <div class="full-name">
                            <div class="fname">
                                <label for="first-name">First Name*</label>
                                <input type="text" name="First&nbsp;Name" id="first-name" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="lname">
                                <label for="last-name">Last Name</label>
                                <input type="text" name="Last&nbsp;Name" id="last-name">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label for="email-id">Email*</label>
                            <input type="email" name="Email&nbsp;ID" id="email-id" required>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label for="subject">Subject</label>
                            <input type="text" name="Subject" id="subject">
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label for="message">Message*</label>
                            <textarea name="Message" id="message" cols="30" rows="10" required></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="submit">
                            <input type="submit" class="submit-button">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
/* RESET */
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    /* border: 1px solid red; */
}

html, body {
    overscroll-behavior: none;
}

html {
    font-size: 16px;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
    background-color: black;
}


/* VARIABLES */
:root {
    --yellowish: #ffed00;
    --whitish: #faf3e3;
    --heading-font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;
    --body-font-family: 'Space Grotesk', sans-serif;
}


/* BG */
body {
    max-width: 100%;
    background-image: url('/images/bg-image.png');
    background-size: 100%;
    padding: 0 5vw;
}


/* TYPOGRAPHY */
h1, h2, h3, h4, p, li, a, span, figcaption, .submit-button, form label, .individual-page-heading {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

p, li, a, figcaption {
    font-family: var(--body-font-family);
    color: var(--whitish);
}

h1, h2 {
    font-family: var(--heading-font-family);
    color: var(--yellowish);
    font-weight: 400;
}

h1 {
    /* font-size: 40px; */
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    line-height: 140%;
    letter-spacing: 0.03em;
}

h2 {
    /* font-size: 30px; */
    font-size: 1.875rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    /* margin-top: 91px; */
}

.button-text {
    /* font-size: 13px; */
    font-size: .813rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    /* line-height: 17px; */
    line-height: 1.063rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.slide-button-text {
    /* font-size: 15px; */
    font-size: 0.938rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: var(--body-font-family);
    color: var(--whitish);
    text-decoration: none;
}

.cta-text, .interjection {
    font-family: var(--heading-font-family);
    color: var(--whitish);
    /* font-size: 13px; */
    font-size: .813rem;
    text-align: center;
}

p {
    /* font-size: 18px; */
    font-size: 1.125rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    /* line-height: 31px; */
    line-height: 1.938rem;
}


.name {
    font-weight: 700;
}

.interjection {
    /* font-size: 15px; */
    font-size: 0.938rem;
}

.project-num {
    font-family: var(--body-font-family);
    font-weight: 700;
    /* font-size: 60px; */
    font-size: 3.75rem;
    color: rgba(250, 243, 227, 0.2);
}

.project-name {
    font-family: var(--heading-font-family);
    color: var(--yellowish);
    /* font-size: 30px; */
    font-size: 1.875rem;
    /* line-height: 60px; */
    line-height: 3.75rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    /* margin-top: 20px; */
    /* -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale; */
}

.submit-button {
    font-family: var(--body-font-family);
    color: black;
    /* font-size: 13px; */
    font-size: .813rem;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 500;
}

form label {
    font-family: var(--body-font-family);
    color: var(--whitish);
    /* font-size: 17px; */
    font-size: 1.063rem;
    font-weight: 400;
}

/* FONT AWESOME ICONS */
i {
    color: var(--whitish);
}


/* SPARKLES */
.sparkle {
    /* width: 90px; */
    width: 5.625rem;
    position: absolute;
    /* width: 6.25vw; */
}

.sparkle-1L {
    top: 5vh;
    left: 5vw;
    /* top: -4vh; */
}

.sparkle-1R {
    top: 81vh;
    right: 5vw;
    /* right: 0; */
}

.sparkle-2L {
    top: 105vh;
    left: 5vw;
}

.sparkle-2R {
    top: 181vh;
    right: 5vw
}

/* GENERAL */
.links {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.button {
    width: 130px;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    border: 1px solid var(--whitish);
    text-align: center;
    /* padding-top: 8px; */
}

.slide-button {
    width: 130px;
    /* height: 37px; */
    border: 1px solid var(--whitish);
    /* padding-top: 7px; */
}

.colored-button {
    background-color: var(--whitish);
    margin-top: 30px;
    /* width: 109px; */
}

.colored-button a {
    color: black;
}

.button a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 7px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    /* background-color: rebeccapurple; */
}

/* PROJECTS DISPLAY SECTION */ 
#projects-display {
    /* background-color: yellowgreen; */
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.projectsdisplay-content {
    /* background-color: orange; */
    height: 80%;
    display: grid;
    justify-content: space-between;
    /* align-items: center; */
    /* display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    justify-content: space-between; */
}

#projects-display .interjection {
    /* background-color: plum; */
    height: max-content;
}

.carousel {
    /* background-color: red; */
    /* max-width: 1296px; */
    width: 90vw;
    height: 488px;
    margin-top: 35px;
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.slide-item {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    /* scroll-margin-top: 188px; */
    /* border: 5px solid salmon; */
}

.slide-content {
    width: 88.1%;
    height: 90%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    border: 2px solid #D38C01;
    background-color: rgba(211, 140, 1, 0.1);
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 49px 28px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.slide-img {
    order: 2;
    /* background-color: teal; */
}

.slide-img img {
    margin-top: 3px;
    width: 613px;
    /* width: 100%; */
    height: auto;
    /* max-width: 100%; */
    object-fit: contain; 
}

.slide-text {
    /* background-color: tan; */
    width: 40%;
    height: 100%;
}

.project-num {
    margin-top: 6px;
}

.project-name {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.buttons {
    display: flex;
    max-width: 313px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 65px;
    /* position: relative;
    top: 67px; */
}

#slide-1 .buttons, #slide-2 .buttons {
    margin-top: 125px;
}

.slide-indicator {
    width: 120px;
    height: 15px;
    margin: 32px auto 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.circle {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: rgba(250, 243, 227, 0.2);
}
  
.current-slide {
    background-color: #D38C01;
}

.slide-item  i {
    /* font-size: 60px; */
    font-size: 3.75rem;
    color: #FAF3E3;
}

.slide1-arrow-left, .slide2-arrow-left, .slide3-arrow-left, .slide4-arrow-left, .slide5-arrow-left {
    float: left;
    /* margin-top: -18%; */
    margin-top: -250px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
  
.slide1-arrow-right, .slide2-arrow-right, .slide3-arrow-right, .slide4-arrow-right, .slide5-arrow-right {
    float: right;
    /* margin-top: -18%; */
    margin-top: -250px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
  
.carousel a:visited {
    color: #FAF3E3;
}



/* CONTACT ME SECTION */
#contact-me {
    /* background-color: violet; */
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.contactme-content {
    /* background-color: skyblue; */
    /* width: 40%; */
    /* width: max-content; */
    height: 90%;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

#contact-me h2 {
    /* background-color: tomato; */
}

#contact-me form {
    width: 453px;
    height: max-content;
    /* background-color: tan; */
}

#contact-me label {
    display: block;
    /* margin-bottom: 7px; */
    margin-bottom: 0.438rem;
}

#contact-me input:not(.submit-button), textarea {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid var(--whitish);
    background-color: transparent;
    height: 45px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: var(--whitish);
    padding: 5px 10px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.fname, .lname {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 44%;
}

.full-name {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

#contact-me textarea {
    height: 120px;
    resize: none;
}

#contact-me form div:not(.full-name, .submit) {
    margin-bottom: 46px;
    margin-bottom: 2.875rem;
    /* background-color: #D38C01; */
}

.submit-button {
    border: none;
    width: 109px;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: var(--whitish);
}

.submit {
    margin-top: -1rem;
    /* background-color: aqua; */
    display: grid;
    justify-content: center;
}

@media  only screen and (min-width: 501px) {
    .for-mobile {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

I tried to figure out what must be hindering the issue and tried to google the problem but didn't find any solution. Tried to build everything step by step but couldn't figure out the issue. I tried to place the slideshow element in the end of the html file and then use css to reorder it before the form element but that didn't work either.